# Exception: ActivityNotFoundException - different name works flawless

Tags: java, android, activitynotfoundexception

I'm building an AndroidApp which uses a java-class `Question.java` which extends `android.app.Activity`.

The Activity is stated in the `androidmanifest.xml` as

```
<activity
        android:name=".gui.android.Question"
        android:label="@string/question_activity" >
</activity>
```

While using this version I get an `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class` everytime I try to start this activity.

However, after hours of not getting any further i tried to make a new Java-Class `QuestionFix.java` plus a new Activity

```
 <activity
        android:name=".gui.android.QuestionFix"
        android:label="@string/question_activity" >
 </activity>
```

The code of `Question.java` and `QuestionFix.java` and calls are 100% equal except the `startActivity`-calls.

Using the `QuestionFix.java`-Class causes no problem at all and everything works as expected.

I tried deleting `Question.java`and then replacing it `QuestionFix.java` but the error persisted. Using a FQN in the `androidmanifest.xml` didn't help.

Is someone able to tell me how I can fix this?